# How to make my div align in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my actual div: 
[Pic1](http://www.4freeimagehost.com/show.php?i=5e750f26e844.jpg)

This is the Pic1 HTML code, it will loop based on the database:

```
<ul class="productUl">
    <li class="productLi">
        <div class="productItem">
                   <!--my div content-->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.productItem{
    width: 15em;
    height: 13.8em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: red;

}
.productUl{
    width: 750px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0;
} 

.productLi{
    width: 15em;
    float: left; 
    padding:0px 5px; 
}
```

But I found that my productItem is up and down, can not in same position Y, I know that I can set the position Y manually, but apart from setting position Y, can I do still keep them in position Y? any ideas on that?

This is what I want:
[Pic2](http://www.4freeimagehost.com/show.php?i=7d5c48897305.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I know what problems, I write the wrong loop for that, I am looping the whole path of html instead of just "  <li class="productLi">
        <div class="productItem">
                   <!--my div content-->
        </div>
    </li>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It works for me](http://jsbin.com/ivuqi).

Your problem is apparently elsewhere.

Can you show us a complete page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

`.productLi {display: inline; /* or inline-block */ }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to float the li, but set its `display` to `inline` or `inline-block`. You might also need to set a `white-space: nowrap` to the ul.

Hope that helps,
harpax